# Default loader splash screen of silverlight is not loaded

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have one silverlight application when I load the application from prod server then the default loader splash screen not displaying but only white screen are there not default Silverlight loader.

What cause this? Or how can I rid of this?

Comment: Apart from the default loader screen, does the app work? Usually the blank screen is when something went wrong.

Comment: Yes apart from working well. after some time app is loaded and all are working well but default loader of silverlight is not loading so user can't get the app is loading or not. Before it was working but when I implemented this solution for remove xap caching then that loader is not displaying. - http://codeblog.larsholm.net/2010/02/avoid-incorrect-caching-of-silverlight-xap-file/

Comment: No, that shouldn't be the problem, this just adds a timestamp to the url for the XAP file, so whenever the XAP gets updated, the client will download it instead loading it from browser cache. By any chance, are you using Chrome?

Comment: Yes but I have checked in all the browsers and not getting the default loader to any of them.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using a custom loader? in your html Param elements check for 'splashscreensource' and if it has any XAML file reference. If so you need to check if the file is on your server when you publish.  <param name="splashscreensource" value="SplashScreen.xaml"/>

Comment: No I am not using the custom loader. I am sure on that. All the default params are there I didn't changed any of them.

Comment: Well with all this info I can only suggest that you open up the console in Chrome or FireBug, and try to load the Silverlight app and look for error events in the console. You can always add your own custom splash screen, there are many tutorials out there how to do it, you can create a progress bar or use just an image.